# rxjs - making requests in parallel and nested requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello I want to make requests in parallel based on an array - it will be as follows

1)perform a singleloginrequest
2)For each entry based on iif condition take the result of iif and perform a chain of operations
3)patch state based on end result of chain operations.

Code I have tried is as follows

```js
 this.questionAnswerService
            .loginToQuriousApi()
            .toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                access_token = response.access_token;
                console.log(access_token);
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    return iif(
                        () => entry.extension == 'pdf',
                        defer(() => this.convertFile.getPdfContentInText(entry.id)),
                        defer(() => this.convertFile.getTextContent(entry.id))
                    ).pipe(
                        concatMap((textContent: string) => {
                            console.log(textContent);
                            ctx.patchState({
                                qnaloading: true,
                            });
                            return this.convertFile.convertFileContent(textContent);
                        }),
                        concatMap((convertedObject) => {
                            return this.convertFile.uploadToQNA(
                                entry.id,
                                convertedObject,
                                access_token
                            );
                        }),
                        concatMap((response: any) => {
                            ctx.patchState({ loading: false });
                            return ctx.dispatch(new UpdateEntries([response.fileEntry]));
                        }),
  
                        catchError((e) => {
                            ctx.patchState({ loading: false });
                            return of('reject: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
                        })
                    );
                });
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                ctx.patchState({ loading: false });
                return console.log('reject: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
```

Here entries is an array of objects. The promise gets executed but for loop does not.

Comment: Use for in loop. eg:
        for (const key in object) {
            if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
                const element = object[key];
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

The `iif` generates an observable that is not subscribed to. This is one of the reasons that the requests are not triggered. You could rewrite it this way:

```
this.questionAnswerService
  .loginToQuriousApi()
  .pipe(
    tap(() => ctx.patchState({ qnaloading: true }))
    map((res) => res.access_token),
    switchMap((access_token) => forkJoin(buildTasks(entries, access_token))),
    finalize(() => ctx.patchState({ qnaloading: false }))
  ).subscribe(); // not a big fan of the empty subscribe, but everything seems to be happening already in the other operations
```

And the `buildTasks` method:

```
private buildTasks(entries: any[], access_token: string): Observable<any>[] {
  return entries.map((entry) =>
    iif(
      () => entry.extension === 'pdf',
      defer(() => this.convertFile.getPdfContentInText(entry.id)),
      defer(() => this.convertFile.getTextContent(entry.id))
    ).pipe(
      concatMap((textContent: string) => {
        console.log(textContent);
        return this.convertFile.convertFileContent(textContent);
      }),
      concatMap((convertedObject) => {
        return this.convertFile.uploadToQNA(
          entry.id,
          convertedObject,
          access_token
        );
      }),
      tap((response: any) => ctx.dispatch(new UpdateEntries([response.fileEntry])),
      catchError((e) => {
        return of('reject: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
      })
    )
  ));
}
```